# Spring boot Activiti implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am trying to add activiti to my existing spring boot project and not able to run a simple example - I am trying to invoke a spring bean service from activiti BPMN. But it keep throwing exception -  Caused by: org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'testService'

I am not sure what else is needed.. Would appreciate any feedback...

Here is my BPMN

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<definitions
        xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
        xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
        targetNamespace="Examples">

    <process id="enrollUser" name="Enroll User Process">
        <startEvent id="enrollStart" />
        <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="enrollStart" targetRef="addUser" />
        <serviceTask id="addUser" name="Add user task" activiti:expression="${testService.testMethod()}" />
        <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="addUser" targetRef="theEnd" />
        <endEvent id="theEnd" />
    </process>

</definitions>
```

This is my Spring Service. Which is in a different maven project included as a jar in the spring web project. If I keep this class in the same project it seems to work fine

```
public Interface TestService {

  public void testMethod();
}

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{

  public void testMethod(){
     System.out.println("Test method called");
  }
}
```

This is my spring boot starter

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init( final RepositoryService repositoryService,
                            final RuntimeService runtimeService,
                            final TaskService taskService) {

        return new CommandLineRunner() {

            public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Number of process definitions : "
                        + repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().count());
                System.out.println("Number of tasks : " + taskService.createTaskQuery().count());
                runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("enrollUser");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Here is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spendfit-console</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <buildEnv>minify-build</buildEnv>
        <activiti.version>5.21.0</activiti.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.. It seems as the implementation class of the TestService has Impl and looks like activiti needs the exact name..so if I changed the BMPN expression to  activiti:expression="${testServiceImpl.testMethod()}" it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

Use named beans and refer them by name in expressions.
This way you can also replace bean for tests easily - same name, mock class in xml spring context replaces (even existing) bean by name:

```
<bean id="oms" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.activiti.extension.bean.OrderManagementService" />
    <constructor-arg ref="mockSettings" />
</bean>
```